# Save multiple textbox values in the same database column MVC4

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am trying to make an application which stores "Ingredients" for a recipe in the database. One recipe can have multiple ingredients which will be entered from new text boxes for each new ingredient.

I am confused of how to configure this in my controller on post to save in the database.

e.g: textbox1: Chicken, Textbox2: potatoes, etc.. on submit goes to a Create() post ActionResult which should find all the text boxes with the same class / value and store it to the recipe database in the same column which can then be retrieved when "ViewRecipe" is called.

A code snippet example would be great !

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What have you tried. What data model are you using? Which kind of database, how are the tables setup? Why a single column and not a child table as ingredients are clearly child records from a recipe table

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308)  gives you some options for dynamically generating collection items

Answer (score 0):

I would use foreign keys for this. As you said, a recipe has multiple ingredients. In Entity Framework this would be:

```
public class Recipe
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    // ...

    public virtual ICollection<Recipe> Recipies { get; set; }
}

public class Ingredient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }

    public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
    public int RecipeId { get; set; }
}
```

Like this you can have a recipe 'Pancaces for 2' with ingredients like '2 Eggs', '50g flour', '1/4 cup buttermilk', ...

Hope I understood your question correctly.

EDIT1:

I would not suggest to store all the ingredients in a single column, what's why I made an example for how to do it with foreign keys. How you would store this (supposed you're creating a new recipe) in a controller. It would be something like this:

```
public ActionResult Post(string recipyName, string[] ingredients)
{
    var recipy = new Recipy
    {
        Name = recipyName,
        Ingredients = ingredients.Select(x => new Ingredient
        {
            Name = x,
            Unit = "pcs.",
            Amount = 1,
        }).ToList(),
    }

    using (var context = new RecipyContext())
    {
        context.Recipes.Add(recipy);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

I really suggest not to store the ingredients in a *single* column. It is not extensible and you would have to do some kind of string trickery to get them out again. Like this everything is clear to everyone who reads your code.

EDIT2: I think this thread [Asp.net razor textbox array for list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150807/asp-net-razor-textbox-array-for-list-items) shows how to integrate such a model into the view rather nicely.

Comment: HI LueTim, I wanted to know how the controller would pick all the values from each text box and save it in the database,

e.g : I have 5 ingredients in the view and I click "Create"

on post, how will the controller recognize and store all the textbox values in the same column in the database ?

Comment: This is almost what I want ! just one thing left here is I see that you are telling me to pass an array of ingredients. How will all the text box values for the ingredients get stored in this array ? 

again, a code snippet would be best and these examples are awesome. Thanks a lot once again for that

Comment: I'm not at home now, I'll reply as soon as I am!