# How to split the array of list into separated one in VIew of C# MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, html, model-view-controller, textbox

I have an input like `["abc","def","ghi"]`. I have to split this into `"abc" "def" "ghi"` in view of C# MVC.
And also i have to display each string value into separate text box of same row.

I have tried like

`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => (String.Join(",", m.editPeriodicTask.args))[1], new { @id = "args", @class = "form-control-list" })`

but I am not getting the right solution. Can anyone please suggest on this.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: If the 2nd list having ["xxx","yyy"] values means, The third text box will be empty

Answer (score 0):

in js u can split array using

```
var s= arrayname.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you are looking for, but it seems using loops is the most common way to achieve it.

[Asp.net razor textbox array for list items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150807/asp-net-razor-textbox-array-for-list-items)

This link might be helpful, in case of three textboxes, you can loop for 3 times instead of the size of the collection.

Hope it helps.