# Razor pages - Model array always null

Tags: c#, razor

I want a text box, bound to an array, to post the form when its changed.

I was following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24150807/asp-net-razor-textbox-array-for-list-items) to get it to work but the property on my model is always null. Why?

Model

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int[] MyInts;
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
{
    if (model.MyInts == null) // <-- Always true
    {
        model.MyInts = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
    }
}
```

View

```
@model TestModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "TestForm" }))
{
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th />
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.MyInts.Count(); i ++)
{
        <th>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(x => Model.MyInts[i],  new { onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
        </th>
}
```

Comment: Can you show the input json which the Endpoint get called with.

Comment: An index is a `Get` not a `Post` by default, you need to create another method to simulate a `Post` for the form.  If you want the array to be bound by default, loose the null check and bind the contents to the `Get` with a `return View(Model)`

Comment: @greg Even though the same approach works in my other forms (where the model has no arrays) I gave your advice a go. I created another method, same signature but different name, to no avail.

Comment: So, what exactly do you want it to do?  Just update the array on change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `MyInts` in `TestModel` is declared as a field.

Instead it must be a public **property** with `get` and `set`.

Change it to:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public int[] MyInts { get; set; }
}
```

---

Furthermore, as mentionned in the comments, your controller must contain a GET and POST `Index` action method.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var viewModel = new TestModel {
            MyInts = new [] { 1, 2, 3, 4 }
            };

        return View(viewModel);
    }

    [HttpPost()]
    public ActionResult Index(TestModel model)
    {
        if (model.MyInts == null) 
        {
            model.MyInts = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        }

        // ...

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, what a stupid thing for me to forget! FWIW, I haven't bothered with separate GET/POST methods, still works.